Error while adding launchDarkly in react app
I was trying to add a feature flag using launchDarkly. I installed launchdarkly-react-client-sdk
using yarn("launchdarkly-react-client-sdk": "^3.2.0",). I tried to add launchDarkly provider(withLDProvider) to one of my main container componnet(not root component).
while running the application. getting below error
"export 'withLDProvider' was not found in 'launchdarkly-react-client-sdk'
anybody know what I am missing?
import React from 'react'
import { withLDProvider } from 'launchdarkly-react-client-sdk';

export const Mycomponent = ({ }) => {
  return (
    ......
  )
}

export default withLDProvider({
  clientSideID: 'client-id',
  user: {
    key: "user_key",
    name: "ebin",
    email: "user@email.com",
  },
})(Mycomponent)


Is the module installed correctly?  What happens if you go into the directory where this component lives, and open a node terminal?  Can you require the export like this: const {withLDProvider} = require("launchdarkly-react-client-sdk")?  Some more debugging details in the question would be helpful.

@MattMorgan , thanks for the reply
I tried
const {withLDProvider} = require("launchdarkly-react-client-sdk")
but still issue exist. getting below error in browser console
ReferenceError: exports is not defined
at ./node_modules/launchdarkly-react-client-sdk/lib/cjs/index.js (index.js:636:1)
at webpack_require (bootstrap:861:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1)`

You should try it in the terminal, not the browser console.  From within the directory where your component is.  And post the results in the question, not in a comment.

I installed a lower version of the package and issue resolved. thanks
